Which number we can get using a calculator that can only perform multiplication of a number by $2$ or $3$, and raising a number to power $2$ or $3$?
Here is a problem from a national mathematical competition held in $2013$:

A calculator can only performs the following operators: Multiplication
of a number by $2$ or $3$, and raising a number to power $2$ or $3$.
If we start by the number $15$ and use operations with this calculator five times, which of the following values can be obtained?
$1)2^8\times3^5\times5^6\quad\quad2)2^8\times3^4\times5^2\quad\quad3)2^3\times3^3\times5^3\quad\quad4)2^6\times3^6\times5^4\quad\quad5)2\times3^2\times5^6$

I used the prime factorization of $15$ which is $3^1\times5^1$ and tested each option:

$1)2^8\times3^5\times5^6$:

From $5^6$ we can realize that the number was once raised to power $2$ and once to the power of $3$. However, it is impossible to have $3^5$ as the power of $3$ should be at least $6$.

$2)2^8\times3^4\times5^2$:

From $5^2$ we can see that it was squared once. It is impossible to obtain both $2^8$ and $3^4$ using the operators five times.

$3)2^3\times3^3\times5^3$:

We first raise $3\times5$ to the power $3$ and then multiply it three times by $2$, so it is impossible.

$4)2^6\times3^6\times5^4$:

From $5^4$ we realize we raised a number to power $2$ twice, but it is impossible to get $2^6\times 3^6$ using operators only five times.

$5)2\times3^2\times5^6$:

It is simply impossible as the power of $3$ should be at least $6$.

If I'm not mistaking, neither of the option can be obtained using only the abovementioned operations. I'm not sure what is the intended answer of this problem, maybe it is possible to multiply a number we got in previous steps in our calculations?

(4) is possible

+1 Nice puzzle!  If possible, could you post a link to this competition.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Thank you! Actually, it was an Iranian competition and the problems are written in Persian language. If it helps maybe I can upload the pdf file.

@Soheil Unfortunately I can’t read Persian.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Ok, by the way I realized this specific problem appeared in Kangaroo $2007$ competition. You can find it by searching the word "calculator" in this pdf.

If you start with $3 \times 5$, multiply by $2$, square, multiply by $2$, multiply by $3$, then square the result is $2^6 \cdot 3^6 \cdot 5^4$.  This is exactly five operations.  The idea is to let the squares act on factors that have been multiplied in.

It is unclear to me whether each operation is immediately evaluated (e.g. by pressing the "=" button on the calculator), or whether more than one operation can be typed in before evaluation takes place. This is relevant, because A multiplied by B raised to the power C is evaluated by a calculator as $A * B^{C}$ rather than $(A * B)^C$.
Assuming more than one operation can be performed before evaluation, answer (2) appears to be correct.
Multiply (3 * 5) by 3. Multiply the result by 2 raised to the power 2, raised to the power 2. Raise the result to the power 2: $\space \space 2^{8} \cdot 3^{4} \cdot 5^{2}$

That only uses four operations, one cube and three multiplies by $2$.  I agree that it is not clear if you are allowed up to five or exactly five operations.

We are not allowed to use the number 15 more than once ?

No, you start with $15$ but can only multiply by $2$ or $3$, square, or cube.
